# Cassandra partition key

Tags: function, cassandra, partition

I have a timestamp column and I want to make the date part of it as the primary key( partition key ), but I can't find a way to do it, I have tried primary key(toDate(timestamp)) and it doesn't work.
Thanks

Comment: `primary key` takes a column name. Have you considered having one `date` column and one `time` column and making the `date` column the partition key?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a separate column for date, insert data into it from your program, and add this column into primary key.  There is no support for function-based parts of the primary key - only existing columns.